# How do I fix "File name too long" issue on apache2?

Tags: php, apache

I have a drupal (php) website in a non-english language where I have links like this:

```
http://example.com/forum/ಕನ್ನಡ‌-ಸ0ಶೋಧಕರಿಗೆ-ನೆರವಾಗುವ‌-ಅದ್ಬುತ‌-ವೆಬ್-ಸೈಟ್
```

When the user copies this links from the browser it's not copied the same it is copied as:

```
http://example/forum/%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1%E2%80%8C-%E0%B2%B80%E0%B2%B6%E0%B3%8B%E0%B2%A7%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%B0%E0%B2%BF%E0%B2%97%E0%B3%86-%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%86%E0%B2%B0%E0%B2%B5%E0%B2%BE%E0%B2%97%E0%B3%81%E0%B2%B5%E2%80%8C-%E0%B2%85%E0%B2%A6%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%AC%E0%B3%81%E0%B2%A4%E2%80%8C-%E0%B2%B5%E0%B3%86%E0%B2%AC%E0%B3%8D-%E0%B2%B8%E0%B3%88%E0%B2%9F%E0%B3%8D
```

And due to this url is requested on the server it throws error message "File name too long". Is there any method to overcome this on php side or on apache2 side?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that apache first tries to load the file at that location, and that's an illegally long file name. It doesn't matter what your app is trying to do with it, because it never gets the chance to see it before apache returns an error.

For details, see the link in the original answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/120397/max-length-of-url-257-characters-for-mod-rewrite

The exact solution depends on what you're trying to do with it, but that link has some suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

So, really not sure if this will fix the problem, but I found a similar issue here, you may want to check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/120397/max-length-of-url-257-characters-for-mod-rewrite